# Find max value 2d array N*N with fewer comparisons

Tags: algorithm, multidimensional-array

I want to find the maximum value in two dimensional array N*N in C with fewer comparisons. I can do it simply with an O(N^2) algorithm, but I think it is too slow.

So, I thought about another way. I simply loop once and search by row and column at the same time, and try to reduce the complexity.  (I guess O(2(n-1))) You can see in this picture what I'm trying to do.

[image: Table]

I use the same loop to check the content of the columns and the rows.

What I want to know is there anything faster? Like Sort the 2D array with O(N log N) complexity?  Assume the values are unsorted.

Comment: I'm guessing that such an approach would slow things down hugely as it impacts cacheing.

Comment: Searching by columns and rows ruins your spatial locality. Remember complexity is not the only thing that determines how fast algorithms run. In reality you won't get faster than getting the max of a flattened 1d array of length N*N.

Comment: Using multicore, you can decrease complexity per core. Like finding max per row per core. Then find max of maximums.

Comment: So my aproach is slower than O(N^2)?

Comment: @MSousa no, it's just slower.

Comment: @MSousa Recall that O(X) means your code runs in `time <= k*X`, where _k_ is a constant. Because your custom algorithm would have poor cache locality, it means that effectively the _k_ value would be larger. It would still however be O(N^2).

Comment: Reducing to below O(N^2) means not comparing some of the elements, how do you find the maximum without accessing the full data set?

Comment: This is language-agnostic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the 2d array of M x M elements is not sorted in any way, then you're not going to do better than O(M^2).

Keep in mind that the matrix has M^2 elements, so sorting them will have complexity of O(M^2 log M^2), since most decent sorts are O(N log N) and here N = M^2.

Comment: It should noted the best solution depends on your actual problem. If you have to repeatedly find the maximum value in a N*N array after performing some minor adjustments to it, then maintaining a sorted array could be much better.

Answer (score 3):

Divide it up into [no, of cores] chunks.  Get max. of each chunk in parallel.  Pick the bones out of the results.

Comment: But each chunk still has loop carried dependencies, so the loop of each chunk could still be further improved by using multiple temporary maxes.

Answer (score 1):

You could probably just cast the array to a 1D array and iterate over the flattened pointer...

I'll explain:

As you probably know, a 2D Array in the memory is stored in a flat state. The Array `char c[4][2]` looks like this:

```
 | c[0][0] | | c[0][1] | | c[1][0] | | c[1][1] | | c[2][0] | ...
 | Byte 1  | | Byte 2  | | Byte 3  | | Byte 4  | | Byte 5  | ...
```

In this example, `c[1][1]` ==  `((char*)c)[3]`.

For this reason, when all members are of the same type, it's possible to safely cast a 2D array to a 1D array, i.e.

```
 int my_array[20][20];

 for (int i = 0; i < 400 ; i++) {
    ((int *)(my_array))[i] = i;
 }

 // my_array[19][0] == 180;
```

As dbush points out (up vote his answer), If your matrix is M x M elements, then M^2 is the best you're going to get and flattening the array this way simply saves you from copying the memory over before any operations.

**EDIT**

Someone asked why casting the array to a 1D array might be better.

The idea is to avoid a nested inner loop, making the optimizer's work easier. It is more likely that **the compiler** will unroll the loop if it's only a single dimension loop and the array's size is fixed.

Comment: so why flattening the array makes a difference?

Comment: unless you manually unroll the loop, it will allow you to avoid the inner loop for the 2D, saving the operations related to the looping itself, and make it easier for the compiler's optimizer to unroll your outer loop (if the array's size is static).

Comment: @Myst For a 20x20 array, I hope you loop up to 400, not 200

Comment: For any loop with 100+ loop count at the inner loop, unrolling the outer loop doesn't make a difference. This is a premature optimization based on not-verified assumption. If you don't know how much the loop overhead of the outer loop accounts for total runtime, then don't assume it, profile it.

Comment: @user3528438 - that's true if you're thinking about this manually. But without an inner loop, there's a better chance that **the compiler** itself will unroll the (outer) loop (for a non dynamically sized array). Also, not that it's a big thing, but you avoid writing the value `0` each time you restart the inner loop (that's an operation) and you minimize the variables in use (freeing memory or, probably, a CPU register)... these are small things. I was thinking about the compiler's optimizations mostly.

Answer (score 0):

dbush certainly has the right answer in terms of complexity.

It should also be noted that if you want "faster" in terms of actual run time (not just complexity), you need to consider caching. Going down the rows and columns in parallel is very bad for data locality, and you will incur a cache miss when you iterate down a column if your data has relatively large rows. You have to touch every element at least once in order to find the max, and it would be fastest to touch them in a "row major" ordering.